# Rabbitmq- How to get publisher side acknowledgement that message has received by consumer

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using Rabbitmq as message broker, I tried but did not found any mechanism by which publisher get some acknowledgement of publised message once that message is successfully consumed by consumer.

It is possible to get some notification at publisher end that publised message's ack/nack given by consumer or not?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the RPC pattern.

Here's the tutorial in C#:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-dotnet.html

Comment: We can't use rpc call because in our case, that one window service will manage message from source device to destination device

Comment: So, if the pusher and the consumer are in the same service, why don't you just put the consume confirmation in the code?

Comment: No Pusher and the consumer are different

Comment: So, I'm sorry but I don't understand your configuration.